# How do I get the index of a JQuery Accordion from the header row ID?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, accordion

I've got an Accordion and I want to get the index of a particular header by its ID.

The accordion is generated from a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProjectList" OnItemDataBound="rptProjects_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div id="accordion">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <h1 style="margin: 0px" class="accordionHeader" id='<%# Eval("projectCode") %>'></h1>

        <div>
           ....some stuff             
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to be able to open the page with a particular section expanded, given the projectCode as a parameter. e.g. user goes to MyPage.aspx?project=ABC123 and the page loads with the ABC123 project open and the other panels collapsed.

The jQuery I have is:

```
var activeProject = $(document).getUrlParam("project");
```

which gets the code.

And

```
$j('#accordion').accordion({
        active: activeIndex,
        collapsible: true
    });
```

which sets the Accordion.

The bit I can't figure out is the bit in the middle. I need to be able to get the activeIndex by iterating over the div to get the index of the row with the relevant project code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like this.  [accordion Active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

```
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" ); //getter 



<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class='headAcc'>First header</h3>
  <div>First content panel</div>
  <h3 class='headAcc'>Second header</h3>
  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
});

//suppose you want to show thee index which starts some text 
var indexToActivate = $('.headAcc:contains("Second header")').index();
alert(indexToActivate);
indexToActivate=indexToActivate-1; //index is zero based for jquery ui. 
$('button').on('click',function(){
    var active = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" ); //getter 
    alert('Current Index is ' + active +" ");

     $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active",indexToActivate ); //setter

     var active = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active" ); //getter 
       alert('Current New Index is ' + active +" ");
});
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2CqEK/3/)

Comment: Doesn't this require you to know the index though? I only have the ID of the header

Comment: it will return the index, which is currently selected.

Comment: How about if I am loading the page from scratch and want to go to the panel with the ID of "abc123"?

Comment: Cheers @Ravi - think I'm getting there. The index seems to be skewed though - I think it's indexing the header and divs (i.e. it's returning an index double what I need)

Comment: @Ben you are getting index based on the header with class.  i am substracting -1, because jquery Ui index starts with 0. now this solution works for you ?

Comment: Actually, I had to use index /2 - the index is the index of the elements in the div, but accordion only indexes the accordion elements it seems